# What is the proper way to configure UploadReadAheadSize in an Azure web service?

Tags: ssl, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure web service sitting behind Azure API Management. This means that the API Management layer uses SSL to talk to my service, along with a client cert for authentication. I am running into what seems to be a common issue with this kind of setup where POST sizes greater than 49152 result in error 413 RequestEntityTooLarge. There are a number of docs that reference the UploadReadAheadSize setting, but all of my attempts to set this value in Web.config result in internal server errors. Here is how I am setting the value:

```
  <system.webServer>
<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="1048576" />
```

Ideally I want to use something larger, but I am just trying to get things to work first. The moment I deploy with this setting all subsequent requests fail with internal server error. I can't find anything in my diagnostic logs to indicate why that failure is occurring.

Looking for any pointers on where/how to set this value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. Note that ideally since I am using only cert auth I should be able to set the sslFlags to "required". I tried that but was unable to get it work work properly with Azure API Management. I kept getting 403.7 errors from IIS. For now I am leaving it set to "negotiate" and increasing the value of uploadReadAheadSize as outlined below:

```
    public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        try
        {
            using (ServerManager server = new ServerManager())
            {
                string siteName = $"{RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id}_Web";
                Configuration config = server.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
                ConfigurationSection accessSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access", siteName);
                accessSection["sslFlags"] = @"Ssl,SslNegotiateCert";
                ConfigurationSection runtimeSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/serverRuntime", siteName);
                runtimeSection["uploadReadAheadSize"] = 5242880;
                server.CommitChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(e.Message);
            throw;
        }

        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?